# Texture setup for Sonic Nintendo Switch model

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

I'm having some difficulty setting up the texture nodes correctly with this Sonic model. The model was ripped from a Nintendo Switch game and the node setup has been confusing me.

Here is the model in question: https://files.catbox.moe/7vwogv.zip

The texture came with different extension names. I am not fully sure on which is which but here's what I believe is the case.

abd- diffuse map

nrm- normal map

prm- a specific map for Switch models. Info here: https://scanmountgoat.github.io/Smush-Material-Research/textures/prm/

crd- I have no idea

Given this information. I used a node setup like this.
[image]

The setup gave me these results:
[image]

As you can see, something went wrong with the setup.

I had to convert the textures from .dds files to .png using the software Paint.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Blender question, this is a question about reverse-engineering a texture format.

Still, the idea seems to roughly be this:
[image: nodes]
https://files.catbox.moe/uinih1.blend

Some textures that you would normally use as "Non-Color" have to be used as sRGB, and some textures that are normally sRGB need extra gamma correction applied. This may just be due to incorrect decompiling.

The body seems to store AO in alpha, not in Blue like your linked page suggests. And instead of roughness it's glossiness (inverted). The channels appear to be used a bit differently between the eyes and the body.
The eye shader in general is probably much more complex, but you would have to compare with how it looks in-game. CDR files seem to be specular tint maps, no obvious way to use them without additional steps or a clear reference.